# Serving static html files using express is not executing the javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am serving a static html file using the `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"views"))`. And when I go to `localhost:3000/first.html` I get the html file. But I don't know if the angularjs and other controller javascript files were executed. I think they were not executed because I use `ng-model` for a button's value and it's just an empty button with no text and the function is not executed for the `ng-click`.

I think maybe it's because only the html file is served by the server without my controller js and my downloaded angularjs which I have `src`'d to in the html. But I don't see a 404 or any error in the console.

And also, when I use a virtual path(like app.use(express.static('',__dirname+"/views"))), I don't get the html file when I go to `localhost:3000/views/first.html`.

This is my server.js:

```
    (function(){

var http = require("http");
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

// app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));
// app.use(express.static('/views',__dirname+'/views')); this is not working

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen('3000');
console.log("Server is listening");

})();
```

My `first.html` which is served by the server:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <base href="localhost:3000/">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./controller.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="firstController">
    First name:<input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last name:<input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="loadView()" ng-model="submit" name="">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the controller.js:

```
    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){

    $routeProvider.when('/first',{
        templateUrl:'/first.html',
        controller: 'firstController'
    })
    .when('/second',{
        templateUrl:'/second.html',
        controller:'secondController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/first'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
console.log("controller");


app.controller('firstController',function($scope,$location){
        $scope.firstName="";
        $scope.lastName="";
        $scope.loadView = function()
        {
            $location.path('views/second/'+$scope.firstName +"/" +$scope.lastName);
        }
        $scope.submit = "submit";
    })
    .controller('secondController',function($scope,$routeParams){
        $scope.firstName = $routeParams.firstName;
        $scope.lastName = $routeParams.lastName;
    })
```

Comment: Can you please paste your `firstController` code as well?

Comment: @DavidR. posted it

Comment: Are there any errors being shown in your console?. Also can you check if there are any 404 errors being shown up in your network tab?

Comment: Man this issue can be sorted as well in your other question why are you making more than 1 questions for the same issue. Once the page is loaded there wont be any case of controller not loading so don't worry about that. Concentrate on the main issue.